# How to visualize triangulation of face in Python

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, delaunay

I have a set of 3D points of each face  which I want to use python to do the triangulation in the face .
Are there any Python libraries (or libraries with a Python wrapper) that can do this?
can scipy.spatial.Delaunay do this calculation?

3d points of face :

```
1;"WallSurface";"{1}";800090.348813119;961230.518131176;-3.07268642306283e-18
1;"WallSurface";"{2}";800097.157193086;961269.934447116;-3.07268642306283e-18
1;"WallSurface";"{3}";800097.157193086;961269.934447116;12
1;"WallSurface";"{4}";800090.348813119;961230.518131176;12
1;"WallSurface";"{5}";800090.348813119;961230.518131176;-3.07268642306283e-18
```

Comment: Maybe this http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ helps?